# Migration of C++ application from 32 bit os to 64bit

Tags: c++

I have a basic question related to the migration. I want to compile the application in 32 bit mode on 64bit platform. The main reason for that is a key third party dependent library is only available in 32 bit complied state.

Question here is whether I will use a 64 bit compiler with -m32 flag using all 32 bit dependent libraries linked to it. Or it should be a 32 bit compiler.

If I use a 32 bit compiler there are warnings related to discarded section etc.

```
Referenced in section .rodata of obj defined in discarded section gnu.linkonce.t of obj:
```

Comment: What compiler? What OS?

Comment: gcc 346 RHEL 4 to RHEL 6

Comment: Also - What warnings?

Comment: Referenced in section .rodaya of obj defined in discarded section gnu.linkonce.t of obj

Comment: @Krythic I wish you could downvote comments right now.

Comment: Interesting. I have never heard of a 64bit compiler that compiles 32bit executables.

Comment: @DROY Can you add the warnings which the compiler is giving you?

Comment: Referenced in section .rodata of obj defined in discarded section gnu.linkonce.t of obj

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333871/please-explain-this-linking-error-referenced-in-section-rodata

Comment: Is there any other suggestion on this?